# HOST_WRITE useful or validation layers wrong?

Tags: vulkan

In the specs about HOST_WRITE_BIT it is write :

> For host writes to be seen by subsequent command buffer operations, a pipeline barrier from a source of VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT and VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT to a destination of the relevant device pipeline stages and access types must be performed. Note that such a barrier is performed implicitly upon each command buffer submission, so an explicit barrier is only rarely needed

However, when you transition (through a vkCmdPipelineBarrier (so in a commandBuffer)) one image from PREINITIALIZED layout with a srcAccessMask to 0 instead of HOST_WRITE_BIT, you get an error :

> validation layer: Source AccessMask 0 [None] must have required access bit 16384 [VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT]  when layout is VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED, unless the app has previously added a barrier for this transition.

Is there an error from the specs? From the validation layers? Is the barrier we are talking about is a pure execution barrier and not a memory one? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My private opinion is: validation layers bug.

It simply checks layout vs access flags and does not seem to be aware of this corner case:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/layers/core_validation.cpp#L9005

There's also a case when you reconsider and do not host write to the `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED` Image at all (and thus need no barrier), isn't it?

I believe the layer message is a `WARNING`, not `ERROR`. It may mean it is "only" a heuristic and some false positives are expected (until they improve the layers, which seem posible, but not so trivial for this case).

---

They even only lately corrected possibility for 0 access flags for the presentation, so it is not far fetched they would (with similar mind) forget something like that in the layers.

I would report an Issue there. They do not bite and worse that can happen is that some Khronos insider more knowledgable than me will explain why you are wrong.

---

That being said, perhaps the `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` is unnecessary too (and `TOP` should suffice)?

Comment: Okay just before your answer I made an issue on github ^^.
So it is a Warning and not an ERROR you are right.
I do not understand what TOP_OF_PIPE come here ^^

Comment: Well, the statement you qoute says there's **no** barrier needed at all. By that logic, if you have a barrier anyway then non-blocking one (`src=TOP_OF_PIPE`) should suffice, no?

Comment: To transition an image layout, you must need a memory barrier. But IMHO you do not need to tell Vulkan that memory become available since it was already performed by the implicit barrier

Comment: You need memory barrier for any use (but it says it was already done implicitly). The implicit barrier also says "visible" not just "available".

Comment: Yes I know.
But to manage memory barrier, I'd go like I wrote here for Vulkan-Tutorial :https://github.com/Overv/VulkanTutorial/issues/29

Comment: Oh, you do have `src=TOP` there too. Nevermind, I somehow assumed in the answer you used the `src=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT` with the access of `0`.

Comment: STAGE Host is only useful when you use an event that is signaled from to the host or to read I think